# nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy, rhel7

I am configuring nginx for reverse proxy in RHEL 7 and here is my config.

```
server {
listen       8080;
server_name  localhost.com;

location / {
 proxy_pass https://server01.com:9443/landscaper;
 root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

 proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
}
```

I have restarted the nginx service. But even after that the proxy is not working for me. Saying "webpage not available"

Kindly help.
TIA.

Comment: Please, show full error message in logfile.

Comment: `2016/09/26 23:19:02 [error] 5406#0: *14 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.208.147.171, server: 169.38.85.136, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://169.38.85.136:8080/landscaperfavicon.ico", host: "169.38.85.152"`
       `Sep 27 05:04:39 ibm-http-server.cfscos2.com systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /opt/rh/nginx14/root/var/run/nginx/nginx.pid: Invalid argument`

Comment: I checked the PID error also. I am having the correct pid in the nginx.pid file.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.iredmail.org/forum/topic10901-iredmail-support-failed-to-read-pid-from-file-runnginxpid-invalid-argument.html ?

Comment: I think PID is not the problem over here.. as you can see the first line, connection refused error...

Answer (score 0):

The Firewall is blocking the port 8080.
So I have changed the port to 443 and tried restarting the nginx service. It is working now.